# cordova secure authentication in ajax

Tags: ajax, cordova, oauth, local-storage

I have an php api service , first time I login , using ajax before send and setRequestHeader and I save my username and password in localStorage:

```
    function Login(username, password) {
    alert(username);
    alert(password);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'APILink',
            type: 'post',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("data" + DecryptData(data.pationts_pationtid));
                alert("data" + DecryptData(data.pationts_nationalid));
                alert("data" + DecryptData(data.pationts_pationtfirstname));
                alert("data" + DecryptData(data.pationts_pationtlastname));
                alert("data" + DecryptData(data.pationts_password));
                alert("data" + DecryptData(data.pationts_password));

                sessionStorage.setItem("username", username);
                sessionStorage.setItem("password", password);

                $.mobile.navigate("index.html");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("error" + xhr.responseText);
                alert("errrrrrr" + thrownError);
            }
        });
}
```

and next time in my ajax  , I Got user and password from session Storage:

```
var username = sessionStorage.getItem("username");
var password = sessionStorage.getItem("password");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:17225/notification/index',
        type: 'post',
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " +      btoa(username + ":" + password));
            },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("data" + data);

        },
        data: {
            deviceId: sessionStorage.getItem("deviceId"),
            platform: device.platform,
            //Orders : orders
            drugname: value.drugname,
            instruction: value.instruction,
            time: value.time,
            dose: value.dose
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("er" + xhr.responseText);
            alert("er" + thrownError);
        }
    });
```

but now I heard that saving password in localstorage is not secure , and I want to use oAuth to secure authentication. but I dont know how to use oAuth in ajax urls. can please help me to do that?

Thank you

Comment: you can use the native storage plugin to save the token in the android shared preferences https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage

Comment: @Akis : is this plugin safe for saving password?

Comment: @Akis : I heard about oAuth in cordova. can use this or not?

Answer (score 1):

In general local and session storage are not considered secure to store valuable user information such is a password or an oAuth token.

For this reason it is suggested to use the native storage method of each platform (shared preferences for android and NSUserDefaults for ios). You can achieve this using the [`nativeStorage` cordova plugin](https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage)

This is a very large topic to discuss so it might be better if you read on already answered questions and articles written about cordova security and oAuth token here are some useful links:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71878/cordova-phonegap-refreshtoken-in-localstorage

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/security/

https://www.checkmarx.com/2015/10/23/the-worst-phonegap-security-issues-and-how-to-avoid-them/